# rake DB tasks hanging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

After I aborted a rake db:drop db:create db:migrate command, I can no longer execute any rails or rake DB related task.
I tried several things already, but nothing worked so far (reinstalling ruby, rails, rake, install and update bundles, delete db and schema files, etc).

This is my database.yml:

```
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: <%= ENV['RDS_DB_NAME'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['RDS_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['RDS_PASSWORD'] %>
  host: <%= ENV['RDS_HOSTNAME'] %>
  port: <%= ENV['RDS_PORT'] %>
```

This is the stack for db:drop, for eg:

```
$ rake db:drop --trace
** Invoke db:drop (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
^Crake aborted!
Interrupt: 
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.0.5/lib/concurrent/collection/map/non_concurrent_map_backend.rb:21:in `[]'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.0.5/lib/concurrent/map.rb:93:in `[]'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications/fanout.rb:57:in `listeners_for'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications/fanout.rb:64:in `listening?'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:167:in `instrument'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:656:in `load_config_initializer'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:614:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:613:in `each'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:613:in `block in <class:Engine>'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:422:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:421:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `each'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `tsort_each_child'
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:415:in `call'
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:415:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in `initialize!'
/Users/user/Documents/dev/workspaces/myProject/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in require'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:253:in `load_dependency'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `require'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:337:in `require_environment!'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:520:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:271:in `block in execute'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:271:in `each'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:271:in `execute'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:213:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/monitor.rb:226:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:193:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:237:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:212:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/monitor.rb:226:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:193:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:237:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:212:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/monitor.rb:226:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:193:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:182:in `invoke'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `invoke_task'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `each'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block in top_level'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:125:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `top_level'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:83:in `block in run'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:drop => db:load_config => environment
```

Appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: What is your `RAILS_ENV`?

Comment: Can you check if any process related to rails is running ? If so, just kill them all and try again.

Comment: Hi, I'm using development RAILS_ENV. I also checked the processes, nothing helped so far. Even reinstalled it all, including recreating the gemset.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try to run the command with specifying your current rails environment?

sample: `rake db:drop RAILS_ENV=development`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Nezir! Tried it earlier and now too... unfortunately I have the same result. Stuck in ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, to be honest I feel a bit ashamed to write the answer here, but might help someone else too! :D

The root cause was byebug... I set Byebug.wait_connection = true, but wasn't aware this would also affect some rake commands...